# Create a sensor with SensorDataUnitType

Tags: azure-digital-twins

I'm trying to create a new device with sensor(s).

This is the payload I'm sending to create the new device:

```
{"Name":"DeviceABC","HardwareId":"D4xxx425","SpaceId":"xxxx-xxx-xx-xx-xxx","Status":"Provisioned","CreateIoTHubDevice":false,"Properties":[{"Name":"VendorName","Value":"MyVendor"},{"Name":"VendorDeviceId","Value":"D4xxx19425"},{"Name":"VendorDeviceType","Value":"electricity"}],"Sensors":[{"pollRate":0,"id":null,"dataType":"Json","dataUnitType":"KilowattHourEnergy","deviceId":null,"portType":null,"port":"electricity","spaceId":null,"type":"Classic"}]}
```

In this case I want to use a built in type. KWh

```
 {
    "id": 186,
    "category": "SensorDataUnitType",
    "name": "KilowattHourEnergy",
    "disabled": false,
    "logicalOrder": 0,
    "friendlyName": "kWh"
}
```

The SensorDataType is :

```
{
    "id": 314,
    "spaceId": "xxxx-xx-xxx-xx-xxxx",
    "category": "SensorDataType",
    "name": "Json",
    "disabled": false,
    "logicalOrder": 0
}
```

When I do this for other devices without specifying a dataUnitType in the sensor object, it works fine. But as soon as I include it i get this:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "400.600.000.000",
    "message": "Invalid datatype/dataunittype combination used on sensor."
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a naming convention between SensorDataType and SensorDataUnitType. The convention is that the SensorDataUnitType needs to end with the full SensorDataType. In your example you have:

```
"dataType":"Json",
"dataUnitType":"KilowattHourEnergy",
```

But according to the convention it should be

```
"dataType":"Json",
"dataUnitType":"KilowattHourEnergyJson",
```

Of course you can't just change KilowattHourEnergy because it's in a system ontology. So to get it working I had to create KilowattHourEnergyJson as a new type.

I guess the most complete answer would include that in your case the SensorDataType probably shouldn't be JSON but should be Energy.

Comment: Thanks Matthijs, is this documented somewhere? I didn't see this in die documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had to piece it together from another user forum and then tested a ton of different combinations in my own instance. Hope this helps!